# Laravel Datatables pagination(when limit used on server side) issue

Tags: laravel, pagination, datatables, yajra-datatable

I have faced problem regarding datatables.I am working in laravel and used `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` package.

In one of my product section, there are 100-200k records. When I hit my product listing, it will take lots of time to load because I am getting all records from the database.

I am trying to get records on the basis of limit but it will create a problem in pagination and searching. Only one pagination link working and all other pages return empty data.

Here below is my server side code:

```
$skip = $request->get('start') != null ? $request->get('start') : 0;
$take = $request->get('length') != null ? $request->get('length') : 10;
$products = Product::skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
$count = Product::get()->count();   
return Datatables::of($products)->setTotalRecords($count)->make(true);
```

ajax response:

```
{"draw":2,"recordsTotal":121,"recordsFiltered":121,"data":[],
```

Here data is empty, I am not sure how to append data while ajax call.

How I code when we have a large amount of records?

Comment: How about `Product::paginate($take)` ?  Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but paginate not work with datatables.Also pagination is handle by datatables.   setTotalRecords($count) will make pagination links.

Comment: @sunil: Have you checked [custom filter](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/collection/custom-filter)?

Answer (score 0):

For handling large data you need to use yajra-datatables server side processing.
in your javascript handle like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ route(' serverSide ') }}',
        columns: [
          {data: 'name', name: 'name'}
        ]
    });
});
```

then in route do something like this

```
    Route::get('/serverSide', function () {
        $products = Product::all();
        return Datatables::of($products)->make(true);
         })->name('serverside');
```

**Edit:**

You were returning collection rather than builder. check these issues in the github [#575](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/575) and [#1053](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1053)

Comment: Hi,  this is not working in my case because it will load all data from product table(Product::all()) . I need to fetch record on the basis of limit like Product::skip($skip)->take($take)->get();

Comment: No, It won't load all data from product table. You should check your XHR request on console panel. Everytime you click on the pagination number it sends an ajax request and load data as per the page length.

Comment: On a quick note, you should use builder to get better result rather than using collection. you should get rid of get() method and setTotalRecords($count).

Comment: Please, check my answer edit. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Nowshad, thanks for your reply..   You mean Product::all()  will fetch records on the basis of start and end limit...

Comment: I know XHR request send start and page length but How i use this on the server side ? Can  Product::all() will handle limit...

Comment: That was just a dummy code to explain. all() is a method for collection in laravel, if you use it your datatable will get slower as these issues i refered. You need to use a query that return a builder like DB::table('products')->get().

Comment: Sorry ,i am not getting you...Can you please let me know how i set start and end limit . I think get()  return all records and the query result is slower.

Comment: Same problem, i have exactly your code where my 'products' are 15 millions rows and it load all at once. It will render only 15 but it loads the entire query, you need to do something specific where you limit your query and show based on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable name `length` with the value of your limit. Ex.:

```
$('#tasks-table').on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
        data['employee'] = $('#employeeId').val();
        data['length'] = 20; //This is the pagination limit data variable
});
```